# This question was based on a blunder.Why does vim give "read only" for file with --w--w--w- permissions

Tags: permissions, vim

I now realise, thanks to a comment by jessie_b, that I made a blunder in describing the circumstances of my problem that is not a problem.. If I can I would like to withdraw this question. With apologies for the trouble caused.

I am practising with vim to refresh my understanding, and to do this I have created a test file, to edit in user mode. When I tried to change to insert mode I was told

`"-- INSERT -- W10: Warning: Changing a read only file"`.

I used `chmod`, in supervisor mode, to change the permissions to permit writing to the file:

```
[Harry@localhost]~% ls -l vim/test
--w--w--w- 1 root root 39 Jul 31 19:08 vim/test
[Harry@localhost]~%
```

But, going back to edit in user mode, I still get the same warning. Please can someone explain this?

---

No mystery after all, changing the permissions to --w--w-rw- solves the (non-existent) problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within vim try the following:  `:set noro` . The file may be set read only from within vim but I have a feeling something weird is going on because you don't have read permissions to the file...you shouldn't even be able to open it.

If I create a test document and chmod 222 I get `[Permission Denied]` when I try to open with vim not read only.

Comment: Thank you Jessie_b for the prompt response.I think I picked out the wrong vim screen-- I've been floundering about in this and got a screen full of odd message. You are correct -- I can't read the file with those permissions.  I will edit my Q to take account of this. Sorry about this.